# Sqoop Access Control of mysql issue

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

In our network, we have very clear access control for mysql database. After writing a sqoop command we discovered that sqoop is trying to connect with mysql from one of the servers in hadoop cluster. Servers in hadoop cluster will not be able to connect to mysql database.

Is there any way to tell sqoop to connect with our mysql from the local machine where we are executing our sqoop command?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop naturally runs as a map reduce job. Therefore the process which is copying the data from mysql, could run on any host on the cluster and often there will be several processes reading data from mysql concurrently.

However, I think you can run Sqoop in "local" mode to stop it running on map reduce by passing `-jt local` to the command, eg:

```
sqoop [tool-name] -jt local [tool-arguments]
```

However if you need to run the exports in parallel, this may be much slower.

Note, I have not tested this myself.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try